# Can I kill the Spike Traps?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I know that in this game, one of the more common traps is the spike trap, which triggers a little time after your character walks on top of it (unless they have the P.A.D. trait).

So, my question is, is it possible to destroy them, temporarily disable them (other than P.A.D.), or are they just invulnerable objects? I have heard that Retribution Runes can damage enemies upon taking damage from them. But, does this property also apply to the spike traps as well?

Thanks for the assistance folks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, spike traps, along with every other thing in the game that deals damage, can be destroyed with Retribution Runes. Unfortunately, you can only achieve that by allowing them to damage you enough that the returned damage is enough to destroy them, which I think depends on what area of the castle you are in.

Comment: Not everything. For example actual spikes (not the traps ones) cannot be killed by retribution runes no matter how much damage they give you.